# why doesn't tsc catch an incorrect implementation of the interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript, union-types

I have a very simple problem. I have a function with a signature:

```
interface Something {
    doIt(param: Sometype | string):void;
}
export class Thing implements Something {
    doIt(param: Sometype | 'string') {
     //...
    }
}
// somewhere else
const myThing = new Thing();

// compile error
myThing.doIt('hello');
```

results in

> Error:(16, 22) TS2345:Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'Sometype | "string"'.

Why does tsc catch the error at `doIt('hello')` and not `doIt( param: Sometype | 'string')`. Should having a literal type conflict with the interface's type signature? I would expect literal `'string'` not to be the same as string. Is this a tsc bug, or something intrinsic about union types or literal strings?

Comment: Your code has no compilation errors. Other than that you have two different types: `SomeType` and `Sometype`, both of which are not included. How do you expect to get help when you fail to give us a producible example to work with? Maybe reproduce it in the playground and share a link for example?

Comment: That "string" in double quotes in the error message tells me that you probably have parameter typed `SomeType | 'string'` somewhere, not `SomeType | string` (note the quotes around 'string'). As others have asked, please provide **complete** and **verifiable** example.

Comment: Do you know the [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) ? Go there, reproduce the problem and then share it with us. Then you might be able to get help.

Comment: Does the actual TypeScript compiler complain about the same issue? Or just IntelliJ?

Comment: why are you using 'string' to specify the argument type?

Comment: yes, this is the mistake i'm wondering why tsc didn't catch-- it does not correctly implement the interface IMO. It only catches it later when using the  concrete method, but not when implementing it. is that expected? To me it is obvious that the literal type is not correct... why isn't it obvious to the compiler? is it because the typeof happens to match?

Comment: Basically yes, literal type `'string'` is a subtype of `string`, so argument type of `doIt` in `Thing` is assignment-compatible with argument type of `doIt` in `Something`, so [according to the rules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance) `doIt` function type in `Thing` is compatible  and more specific than `doIt` in `Something`, so override succeeds and there is nothing to complain about in these class definitions.